# Confused about 301 redirect, need suggestions

Tags: .htaccess

I want to 301 redirect a .net site to a .com site of mine but not sure about the correct way to redirect the inner pages. Here's what I want to do:

1. redirect the homepage of .net site to an inner page of .com site - oldsite.net to newsite.com/ranking-page.php
2. redirect some inner pages of this .net site to the related inner pages of .com site, like this:

oldsite.net/party-poker/ to newsite.com/party-poker.php

oldsite.net/us-poker/ to newsite.com/us-poker-sites.php

and 2-3 more inner page urls to be redirected to newsite.com's related inner pages.

1. redirect all the other inner pages of oldsite.net to newsite.com/ranking-page.php

Let me know if it's possible to do something like this through htaccess. If it's not possible, I'd like to simply 301 the whole oldsite.net site and all its inner pages to newsite.com/ranking-page.php. Again, let me know how do I do that with htaccess.

I tried 2 different ways but it didn't work. #1 I used this code to redirect the whole oldsite.net site to newsite.com/ranking-page.php like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.com/ranking-page.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this redirects the inner pages to similar url structure like oldsite.net/strategy/ to newsite.com/strategy/ and I do not have pages/url structure like this on newsite.com. Tried a few other ways but nothing seems to be working... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a redirect for each case:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newsite.com/ranking-page.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^party-poker/$ http://newsite.com/party-poker.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^us-poker/$ http://newsite.com/us-poker-sites.php [L,R=301]
# the other 2-3 inner page urls

# finally, everything to ranking page
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com/ranking-page.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You sir, are a rockstar! Thanks a ton boss - you're the best! :)

Comment: Hey bud just 1 more question. If I use the content on the oldsite.net on some other site, will that be a problem? I mean all its pages have been redirected to newsite.com/ranking-page.php now, so it doesnt matter if I use the content on old site on some new site of mine...?

Comment: @user2738855 don't see why that would be an issue unless you've created links that include the hostname (e.g. `<a href="http://oldsite.com/some/content.html">content</a>`)